# The Asset Publisher not only displays selected customized assets by manual selection [Liferay 7.2]

Tags: liferay, assets, liferay-7

I am trying to publish some assets using Asset Publisher and manual selection. The problem is that Asset PUblisher is displaying many assets, not only those ones that I selected.

This is my assets selection configuration:

[image]

And these are my display settings:

[image]

Is there any extra configuration that I am missing? Thanks in advance

Comment: many assets what ?

Comment: @DanieleBaggio yes, when I select a web asset like in the first image, I get many assets not related with the asset I selected. So think about this custom template's code:

`<p>${entries?size}</p>`

It prints more than one entry, but I just selected one asset (I refer to the first image). Did I make myself clear?

Comment: You mention a custom template: If that is part of the question, please post it as well. Without, this question is a configuration question and off-topic on Stackoverflow (see [help/on-topic]) but would be on-topic in the Liferay community on https://liferay.dev/. e.g. I could sense that the template might enumerate the wrong collection.

Comment: No update for 5 days? Seems not to be a problem any more. Voting to close as off-topic for stackoverflow (as described above, the way this question is phrased, it is about software usage, not about programming)

Answer (score 0):

In that case i recomendy use view content widget.
Else it's not option, Try are selection the Number of items to Display as 1, or delete de publisher content widget before, then add to page.